# Darcs local patches

Tags: dvcs, darcs

Is there any way to have Darcs maintain a repository of "local" patches?  In particular, I have a project with a few branches:

```
/project.dev
/project.live
```

Both of the branches have different configuration options (for example, for the database connection, deployment, etc).  I would like these files to be tracked, but not globally.  In particular, I don't want darcs to ask me if I want to push/pull these patches, **ever**.  Can this be done without resorting to another DVCS in conjunction with darcs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't supported at present, but it is something that a lot of people would like, so we have actively discussed adding something like Mercurial's [phases](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases). There's no ETA though.